# Can i use tubing for drain-water under my sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I have to change the dranage under my sink the pipe is in the way for some kitchen appliances.

I can't find any pipes that would work for me, so i consider doing a fix using tubes.

My plan is to the bend of an existing pipe and replace it with a tube that fits on the outside of the tubes and keep it in place with a hose clamp. This would allow me to move the tube so it's not in the way. Would this work? What kind of tube should I use and is there anything else I should think about?

Comment: Making the drain assembly flexible so that it can be moved around will most likely interfere with proper operation of the P-trap that keeps sewer gas from coming up into your sink and kitchen.

Comment: Knowing where you are in the world will allow feedback on compliance with local building codes as well. (Whether or not that matters to you, it is useful to include that information for those using this site as a reference)

Comment: Is this question different than your [previous question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/82959/33)?

Comment: I'm in sweden. @Tester101, I felt my previous question was a bit specific and not very useful to other people. Maybe I should delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Sweden, but here in central U.S. a kitchen sink will be 1 1/2" tube size. This is different than 1 1/2" DWV which is in the wall, but again I don't know how plumbing is run in Sweden. Cost wise, tubing is not much less than the tubing to run a trap, so I would honestly skip the tubing, and run hard pipe. It will be less apt to give to any expansion or contraction with temperature changes, and overall *be more reliable* in the long run.